# Error in cypress: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: vue.js, testing, cypress

This is my test component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    props: {
      msg: String,
    },
    data () {
    },
  }
</script>

<style>
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid steelblue;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
```

And this is my test:

```
import { mount } from '@cypress/vue'
import HelloWorld from '../../src/HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld', () => {
    it('renders a message', () => {
        const msg = 'Hello Cypress Component Testing!'
        mount(HelloWorld, {
            propsData: {
                msg,
            },
        })

        cy.get('h1').should('have.text', msg)
    })
})
```

Below is the output in Cypress when I run `yarn cypress open-ct`:

[image]

Comment: same problem here. Have you been able to solve the problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late but the solution for me was to change `import { mount } from 'cypress'` to `import { mount } from 'cypress/vue2` in the test file. That solved my problem.